# Conditional formatting for a Conditional minimum

Tags: excel-2010

I am struggling with the following - I am attempting to highlight a conditional minimum using conditional formatting, omitting 0 values for a specific dataset. The conditional maximum seems to work fine, but the conditional minimum does not.

The formula I am using for my conditional maximum (successfully):

```
=AND(Z17=MAX($Z$17:$Z$616*(A$17:A$616=A17)),A17>0)
```

The formulas which so far do not seem to work for the minimum:

```
=AND(Z17=MIN($Z$17:$Z$616*(A$17:A$616=A17)),A17>0)
=AND(A17>0,A17=MIN(IF(A$17:A$616=A17,(Z$17:Z$616))))
```

If I take out the `A17>0`, 0 values are being highlighted instead (which are really dummy values here at is a template for which people can input a dataset with variable numbers). Also note that the sets in the ZColumn-set for which `A17>0` will never have 0 values.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this as your conditional formatting formula:

```
=$Z17=MIN(IF(($A$17:$A$616=A17)*($Z$17:$Z$616<>0),$Z$17:$Z$616))
```

It will highlight the column Z minimums for each different value in column A.

See this [Daily Dose of Excel post](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/03/23/maxif-and-minif-with-multiple-variables/) for a discussion.